# Checking for multiple occurrence of character repeated or spread out in string with regex

Tags: java, regex, string, multiple-matches

Having syntax trouble, I'm new to using regex. I'm coding in java.

I need to check if an apostrophe is used more than once in a string. Multiple apostrophes can either be  consecutive or spread out over the string.

For example: `Doesn't'work` or `Can''t`

I have an `if` statement, and I want it to evaluate to `true` if there is more than one apostrophe:

```
if(string.matches("\\'")){ 
.
.
}
```

any help would be great!

Comment: Show us how are you using it?

Comment: Don't the docs have syntax examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to use string.matches

IMHO you don't need it. You could just do this:

```
String s = "Doesn't'work or Can''t";

int lengthWithApostrophes = s.length();
int lengthWithoutApostrophes = s.replace("'", "").length();

if(lengthWithApostrophes - lengthWithoutApostrophes >= 2) {
    // Two or more apostrophes
}
```

---

If you want to do it with a regex, this is the first thing that came in my mind

```
s.matches(".*'.*'.*")
```

Comment: @Juliana You're welcome! If you think that this is the best answer, don't forget to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)! :)

Comment: How can you think this is better? It an absurd amount of code to do a simple task.

Comment: @pguardiario Did you try your regex with the example string she gave us, using the `matches` method? It doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, Your eventual regex is fine, but the ending .* is unnecessary.

Comment: @pguardiario Ok, but i'm talking about your answer, did you test it?

Comment: Yes, `(.*'){2}` is the same as `.*'.*'` (but in a DRY'er fashion). the `//` delimiters are standard for regex notation. My answer is technically simpler and more correct.

Comment: @pguardiario Just check it with java, it won't work. `"Doesn't'work or Can''t".matches("(.*'){2}")` returns false, which is wrong :) Same for `"Doesn't'work or Can''t".matches("/(.*'){2}/")`

Comment: Ok, well I have no way to check this, but obviously java's regex understands such a simple pattern, therefore you must be doing something silly.

Comment: @pguardiario They do. The fact is that the `matches` method is designed to check **the whole string**. So, for example if the regex is `.*'.*'`, the `matches` method evaluates it as `^.*'.*'$`, which is not what she wants to do. So it is **necessary** to add an extra `.*` at the end of the regex.

Comment: No, that's simply wrong, it's actually an example of why so many bad regex answers get voted up. A regex matches when it's pattern matches against a string, and it's as simple as that, please read up on regex pattern matching before attempting to post answers to regex questions in the future.

Comment: @pguardiario Did you read the comment? **Java developers designed the matches method to check the whole string**. Your regex is right, but doesn't work with the `matches` method. Mine does work with the `matches` method. Because when you use `matches(regex)`, the regex becomes `"^" + regex + "$"`. That's how the `matches` method was designed.

Comment: @pguardiario if you don't, you simply have to check javadocs, and then test it yourself. if you don't know how java works, then don't post wrong answers.

Comment: I'm not interested in your backwards logic. I posted the proper regex. That's the right answer whether you like it or not.

Comment: @pguardiario It's not my backwards logic. You should read the question, it's not about a generic regex, it's about a **regex that works with the java String#matches method**. Your solution is a valid regex but doesn't work with that method, so your answer doesn't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Ridiculous. I stand by my answer and my objection to yours.

Comment: +1 For alternative to regex (and also because the downvoter is just silly and obnoxious).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a regex for this. Since you are only looking for more than one occurrence, you can make use [`String#indexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) and [`String#lastIndexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) methods:

```
if (str.contains("'") && str.indexOf("'") != str.lastIndexOf("'")) {
    // There are more than one apostrophes
}
```

Comment: Just a note: you pointed to `indexOf(int)` while you are using `indexOf(String)` :)

Comment: How is this preferable? This makes me want to run screaming.

Comment: @pguardiario I use regex only where it is really required. And if you want to run screaming on this solution, then perhaps you would be screaming on every programming solution you see.

Comment: The question was regarding regex. Regex is a simpler solution in this case. Your solution is a mess and you should really know better.

Comment: @pguardiario. May be I should know many things better. But trust me, I know what I'm talking about in this particular case. I've a feeling that you are frustrated with your regex solution being downvoted (I wasn't the one though), but let me tell you, your regex doesn't work in Java. Java regex don't need the delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(string.matches(".*\\\'.*\\\'.*")){ . . }
```

Comment: It won't work. The `matches` method Checks all the string, so your regex is checking if `string` starts with apostrophe and ends with apostrophe

Comment: There is no need for escaping. Just remove all ``\``.

Comment: It will work, but there's too much escaping and the final .* is extraneous

Comment: @pguardiario: The final `.*` is not redundant. Remember this is `String.matches` in Java, and it will test whether the WHOLE string matches the regex